# ESXi 6.5 Pink Screen of Death

Tags: vmware-esxi, server-crashes, hypervisor

I have a server that seems to be cursed. Every 2-5 days it fails
*(I'm still pretty new to this stuff)*

I've spent the last couple weeks or so trying to find solutions. But I'm clearly not getting anywhere. Any reference to a PSOD I've found is related to much older versions, directly caused by a VM running on the box, HP iLO drivers, or some other situation that doesn't seem to apply to my issue.

I wasn't able to get anything useful out of the wall-o-text, other than something about the vCenter Server agent and possibly something about my 10g NIC? (which I've since removed, just in case)

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qGYUT4JNJK9qfR5VH9l26XOHj68wH6pu) are a couple pics.

I should have more, but I apparently didn't save them?

## Hardware Currently In Use

- Motherboard = [Supermicro X9DRI-F-O](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B007HW39ZM/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- CPU = 2x [Xeon E5-2670](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B0163AWD96/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- RAM = 32GB
- HBA = 2x [SAS9211-8I](https://smile.amazon.com/SAS9211-8I-8PORT-Int-Sata-Pcie/dp/B002RL8I7M/ref=sr_1_3?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1521749413&sr=1-3&keywords=lsi%20hba)
- PSU = 700w

---

## Hardware I've tried so far

- **3 motherboards**

  - Supermicro X9DRI-F-O
  - intel extreme dz77ga-70k
  - intel Desktop Board DX58SO
- **2 sets of CPUs (a dual socket set and a single socket)**

  - Xeon E5-2670
  - Xeon X5650 (This may not be right right cpu, but it's currently buried
- **3 PSUs**

  - 550w
  - 700w
  - 850w
- **2 sets of tested RAM (one set ECC)**

  - 32GB DDR3 ECC
  - 16GB DDR3
- **2 install devices (one spinning rust, one USB)**

  - [HDD](https://smile.amazon.com/Seagate-Desktop-3-5-Inch-Internal-ST250DM000/dp/B005CT56XU/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1521747914&sr=1-2&keywords=ST250DM000)
  - [USB](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00HQ0MF14/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

## Other things I've Tried

- Reinstalling
- Re-downloading install media and reinstalling from a different (and the same) USB drive
- Having no VM's running

---

I kind of cheaped out on the [chassis](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BQY3916/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1), so I'm not super confident in the backplanes. I've also tried swapping the bays around. and just connect straight to a SATA connection on the motherboard

And the server is behind a [UPS](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00429N192/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o09_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1), so power weirdness shouldn't be an issue.

I'm 99% sure there is something obvious that I'm missing, but after smashing your face into a wall for a while it starts to get hard to see. Luckily I needed to start posting questions to get rep anyway..

Comment: Well, none of these mainboards are on the [HCL for ESXi 6.5](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php). Get supported hardware.

Comment: fair enough, thank you. looks like switching back to xen or proxmox is what i'm going to have to do

Answer (score 2):

of course you should use supported hardware if possible. There are also driver-sets for different vendors like HPE or Dell. So it simply could be a driver problem.

Another thing that i don't understand is why are you using Build 4564106 if you already reinstalled ESXi?

The current Build is 7388607. I don't know the whole patch history but i think it could not be bad to use the newest version with the newest bugfixes...

Comment: Because people [never update their VMware installations](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/6195/13325). I don't understand it.

Comment: That may be pictures from the earlier crashes, but i'll double check that I reinstalled with the newest version and will look into drivers

I'm gonna be a little peeved if i re-installed using the same old version instead of the new one lol >.< thanks for the help

Comment: doesn't appear to be build related. newest pic with build 7967591. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JmZtQ-nk2SrSP6sVOvB5qhEKPJ2NvAcz

Comment: Note that the newest version of ESXi is not available for install. You have to download and install the newest patches manually after the installation.